# jsPDF "Cannot read property 'toFixed' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jspdf

When I first save a document, it works great! Just like it should. However when I save it again, without reloading, I get this issue.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toFixed' of undefined

I'm using the older version of jsPDF for other reasons, but I can't seem to get it working on the newest version as well. Then it will just say

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cell' of undefined

So here's my code, which is using jQuery 3.2.1 and jsPDF v0.9.0

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("a.pdf_btn").click(function(event) {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-target"); // Look for the data-target
    doc.fromHTML($(id).html(), 15, 15, {
      'width': 170,
      'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save("<? echo str_replace(" ", "", $_SESSION['comp_TESTING']); ?>Test<?php mt_rand(1,99);?>.pdf");
  });
});
```

I think it's weird that it works only first time. Am I doing something wrong here?

Kind regards